# InvalidCastException on XAML FlipView Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have a `FlipView` control in my Store app and my `FlipViewItem`s are bound to an ObservableCollection.

Each `FlipViewItem` is a `TextBox`. At runtime, I get an `InvalidCastException` when I try this:

```
TextBox textbox = flipView.SelectedItem as TextBox;
```

Why is that? The `FlipViewItem` is a `TextBox`, and I am casting it to a `TextBox`. If I don't cast, I get an exception anyway. So what's the deal? How do I get a `TextBox` out of my `FlipViewItem`?

Here is my XAML if it helps:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipper"
          ItemsSource="{Binding secret}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="{x:Null}"
          BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
          BorderThickness="0"

          SelectionChanged="flipper_SelectionChanged"
          Loaded="flipper_Loaded">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="flipViewItemTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"
                     IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
                     IsColorFontEnabled="True"
                     IsRightTapEnabled="True"
                     IsTapEnabled="True"
                     IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"
                     Background="{x:Null}"
                     BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     AllowDrop="True"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"

                     TextChanged="flipViewItemTextBox_TextChanged"
                     />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, your SelectedItem is your item from ItemSource. In your case it's should be a `secret` item.

Didn't try it with flipview, but I talk about datagrid and other container like datagrid.

Comment: Yep. But I need to make changes to the TextBox that `secret` is in so why can't I get a textbox from the items in flipview control? it's so weird. Every flipview item has a textbox which has Text property bound to a collection I can get the collection item from flipview but why can't i get the textbox? I need the textbox too.

Comment: Maybe you can try with `flipView.ContainerFromElement(flipView.SelectedItem )`, but I don't know if the flipView have this method (it's coming from a datagrid).